# How to remove trailing newline of last element of numbered list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Removing presentation error

```
myList = []
for i in range(1, 51):
    myList.append(i)

a, b = map(int, input().split())
# give space in between when entering second input i.e. b

for item in myList[a:b]:
    print(item)
```

Above code giving me output as follows:
Actual Output:
2\n
3\n
4\n
But want as follows:
Expected Output:
2\n
3\n
4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a condition to check what is the last item of your `myList`. The function `print` has some parameters you can take advantage of.

```py
myList = [i for i in range(1, 51)]
a, b = map(int, input().split())
# give space in between when entering second input i.e. b

for i, val in enumerate(myList[a:b]):
    if i == len(myList[a:b]) - 1:
        print(val, end='')
    else:
        print(val)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: In the example I posted, you can see that I verify what is the last item of you list. That is the fist if statement. If it is last, I am printing the last item, but this time I am telling print to end with an empty character. This means that the print will not end with a new line in your case `\n`. Have a look on the default behavior of [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)